# LARAVEL HOMESTEAD SQLSTATE[HY000] [1862] Your password has expired. To log in you must change it using a client that supports expired passwords

Tags: php, mysql

I have gotten stuck all day with an expired password for mysql. I have followed other similar questions yet I continue to get the same password expired error. I have uninstalled and reenstalled Mysql with homebrew. I have restarted the mysql server. I have deleted,changed and created homestead users in mysql and even uninstalled then reinstalled[image] homestead and vagrant.None of this is working. What should I do?

[image]

[image]

Edit-Update:

I can make it into the mysql with the following using sequel pro:

[image]

but having this in the .env file reproduces the expired password error.:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

What I've done for now is to set the password again.

1. `vagrant ssh`
2. `mysql -u homestead -p`
3. Type in the existing password (secret)
4. `SET password=PASSWORD("secret");`

This has started happening on all my vagrant boxes, some that haven't even been provisioned lately which means wildly different MySQL versions, typically 5.6+ at least. It's not a long term fix either sadly. These steps will have to be repeated until someone can track down how to fix it for good.

Edit: I'm using Homestead v2 with a tweak to use this box: https://atlas.hashicorp.com/laravel/boxes/homestead/versions/0.3.3. They're all the same MySQL version which explains why I'm seeing this across the board.

The current version of MySQL for that box is 5.7.9 and the [password expiration policy](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/password-expiration-policy.html) has the default `default_password_lifetime` at 360. The password in that box has a `password_last_changed` time of `2015-11-13 03:50:18`. 360 days after that is `2016-11-07 03:50:18` which I believe precisely explains why this occurred in the first place.

I checked all of the possible MySQL config locations and I see nothing overriding this default. I believe setting it to 0 or altering the user to never expire (after the set password command) should be enough to fix it for good, I hope.